# I am trying to change the string permanently but this code isn't doing it

Tags: c, string, function, reverse

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h> //**Just To Add getch() function**
    int length(char *p){
        int i; //**I know That these variable are not the same as they are in other function**
        for(i=0;*(p+i)!='\0';i++);
        return i;
    }
    void strrev(char *p){
        int i,len;
        len=length(p);    
        char cpy[len]; //**Already Tried to change it to some fixed value**
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
            cpy[i]=*(p+len-i);
        }
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
            *(p+i)=cpy[i];
        }
    }
    int main(){
        char str[20]="computer";
        strrev(str);
        printf("%s",str);
        getch(); //**to Stop The Screen**
        return 0;
    }
```

I have tried changing the array size to a fixed value i also tried with changing the variable but there is no mistake in my syntax.

Comment: Just iterate to `len >> 1`. Give this a try.

Comment: If you iterate to the length of the string, you reverse it and reverse it back. You have to go only half way.

Answer (score 1):

By recommendation of @Yunnosch, here is my comment as an answer.

In your function `strrev` you iterate over the whole string i.e. the iterations for `i` from zero to `len / 2` you correctly grab the characters, but the remaining iterations just undo this again.

Thus, just iterate from zero to `len >> 1`. The bit-shift ensures integer division.

```
void strrev(char* const str)
{
   const size_t len = strlen(str);
   for(size_t i = 0; i < (len >> 1u); ++i)
   {
     const size_t j = len - 1u - i;
     char c = str[i];
     str[i] = str[j];
     str[j] = c;
   }
}
```

Comment: @TomKarzes you're right, one has to use the plain `size_t` instead of `std::size_t`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using this `cpy[i]=*(p+len-i);`  means you are placing  `\0` terminator in the beginning of string `cpy`. in which case your both of strings will start with `\0` and so `printf` will do nothing.

so change `cpy[i]=*(p+len-i);` to `cpy[i] = *(p + len - i-1);`.

Comment: Thanks For Responding, And I Know That Way But I Want To Know Whats Wrong In My Code!!

Comment: @ShishirTiwari the code is not wrong , but since you use `%s` it's not doing anything , if you use `%c` instead and loop over returned string from function to print it char by char you will do successfully without any change in your code.(also it's better to change `strrev` to something else)

Comment: Are you aware of the other answer, which describes that the terminator is indeed swapped to the beginning at the start of the loop, but then swapped back to the end at the end of the loop? I find it convincing. Could you elaborate why you think that irrelevant? If it is true it would mean that your analysis (that printf is not outputting anythign) misses the point. Did you try what the output is? I admit I did not, but probably would have to support an answer like yours.

Comment: @Yunnosch I debugged the code and I saw that the return of function is a string starts will terminator.

Comment: @Yunnosch I compiled the code and `printf` didn't output any thing.which I found very convincing ` for(i=0;i<len;i++){ cpy[i]=*(p+len-i); }` the `\0` is placed at the first of `cpy` and also `c` of "computer" will be lost.(since the function `length` is not counting `\0` like `strlen`) and in the next loop the string `cpy` is getting copied in `p` and `p` will return to `main` and when I ran the program nothing was printed but when I used `for(int i=0;i<9;i++) printf("%c ", str[i]);` for printing string in main `it actually gives me the expected output .

Comment: @Yunnosch by expected output I mean it leaves a space as `\0` and then print reversed string, but with `printf("%s",str);` the program didn't output anything. and when I debugged the code ,I saw that `str` after `strrev` will become `""`.